# Windows Service not writing text file after installation in Windows

Tags: c#

I have created a console based app and running fine, and same app converted into windows services. When i install it through visual studio for debugging its install and run smoothly, but when the code flow goes to change the app.config file value 0 to 1 it throw an exception UnauthorizedAccessException' and access denied.

Comment: The WindowsService process would be running under a account different from what the Visual Studio might be running under.

Comment: Yes, @sachin is right. Go to START->Services to see the list of your services and find your app. See what is the user. Perhaps change the user or grant him additional rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be due to one of these 2 reasons:

- **If you are not accessing file using an absolute path, the service might be looking for the file at a location other than where you are expecting.**

  > Services are started from an application called Service Control
  >   Manager. This application lives in the system directory 
  >   **%WinDir%\System32**
  >
  > On a Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bits this path is actually :    **%WinDir%\SysWOW64**
- The WindowsService process could be **running under an account different
  from what the Visual Studio might be running under**.

  Either you can make the service run under an account that already has permission to the file or give permissions to the account that the service is already running under.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for your feedback my problem has been solved......

Comment: Which one was the issue?

Comment: U said right that "The WindowsService process would be running under a account different from what the Visual Studio might be running under" that was the issue

Comment: Ok, you should accept the answer that solves the problem in Question. This might help users who later visit this post while trying to find solution for a similar problem.